# Create Azure DSVM with custom image templates

Tags: azure-dsvm

Our security team only allow VMs created from custom golden images, so how can I create Azure-DSVM from enterprise custom image?

Answer (score 1):

DSVM is a marketplace image itself. You can create a DSVM using the image and then customize it as per your security needs.

Thanks